# EGit - more than 200 bases exception on merge

Tags: eclipse, git, svn, egit

I was trying to merge the master branch into another branch.

I recieved the following wierd exception:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Merging with refs/heads/master".
Exception caught during execution of merge command. org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoMergeBaseException: No merge     base could be determined. Reason=CONFLICTS_DURING_MERGE_BASE_CALCULATION. "More than 200 merge bases for:
a f66d2b5e393e04cea11e4b92a54e71bb6180cd5e
b 8ca54ccc2c1df01813049f13d7ab88d0a7d28060 found:
count 2"
```

Any ideas what this is?

PS: Other branches do merge into master just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have been bitten by [JGit bug 419641](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=419641), which has been fixed in EGit 3.2 and above.

To work around this, do the merge on the command line, or see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12227221/305973) for a workaround in EGit.

Answer (score 1):

For your information, I just ran into this same exception pulling the origin/master into my local/master. Yet both EGit and JGit are in version 3.3.1

Pull result in Eclipse:

```
Exception caught during execution of merge command.
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoMergeBaseException: No merge base could be determined.
Reason=CONFLICTS_DURING_MERGE_BASE_CALCULATION.
"More than 200 merge bases for:
a f13ef2fd1cbcdae32a8b275fdec244819c219679
b 2bfec3e6ae8963376e9618c800dba67081616fea
found: count 2"
```

I've tried 3 or 4 times with hard resets in between and with or without --no-ff but always got the exact same response.

Pull result in command line (in French, sorry, but it worked and I just have a tiny conflict in a tiny file):

```
$ git pull
Compression automatique du dépôt pour une performance optimum. Vous pouvez aussi
lancer "git gc" manuellement. Voir "git help gc" pour plus d'information.
Counting objects: 7132, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5341/5341), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7132/7132), done.
Total 7132 (delta 4315), reused 2693 (delta 1317)
Fusion automatique de src/path/to/tiny/file
CONFLIT (contenu) : Conflit de fusion dans src/path/to/tiny/file
La fusion automatique a échoué ; réglez les conflits et validez le résultat.
```

So I wonder if this is the same bug and, if it is, if it has indeed been fixed. :)