# Multiple common ancestors were found and merging them resulted in a conflict

Tags: eclipse, git, atlassian-sourcetree, merge-conflict-resolution

I am performing salesforce deployments. The current setup is:

1. **Dev** org is pushed from **develop1** branch.
2. **UAT** org is pushed from **UAT1** branch.

Every 2 weeks we do a **Mergeback** of **UAT1 into develop1**. Which is later deployed onto the dev org.

This has been working for me until now. Currently I have been continuously seeing below error while merging in eclipse:

```
**"Multiple common ancestors were found and merging them resulted in a 
conflict"**
```

I tried using Eclipse Neon/Mars with Egit 4.*. I am unable to carry out the merge activity and resolve the conflicts.

Based on the answers in the below question:

[How to work around "multiple merge bases" error in EGit Eclipse plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223439/how-to-work-around-multiple-merge-bases-error-in-egit-eclipse-plugin)

I do not want to go about the cherry picking of the merge activity since It will be a very cumbersome task.

Is there another tool which can handle this? I have installed sourcetree, but I am not sure if this would help.

Comment: What is a mergeback?

Comment: It's worth noting that this is *not* a *Git* bug. It's specific to Eclipse. If you exit Eclipse and work with command-line Git you can get your merge done (it will require some hand-massaging, but all of that is possible). To see what "multiple ancestors" means, read through the first few chapters of [my stalled-out book](http://web.torek.net/torek/tmp/book.pdf) where I go into the details of graphs Lowest Common Ancestor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by doing the following:

1. Used source tree to merge the local copies of the remote branches develop1 and UAT1---> Source tree was able to handle the multiple ancestor problem and gave me a list of conflicts.
2. Since I was not very comfortable with using Source tree for conflict resolution, I eclipse to open the code and resolve the conflicts in the Git staging window.(I'd like to know if there is a similar external editor that allows you to accept the changes and reject like eclipse).
3. Staged and committed the files using eclipse.

This is a long workaround, and I wonder if I will see the Multiple ancestor issue when I perform the mergeback again after 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseGit on Windows was also successful in merging such a situation.